Cant graph this extremely skewed function
I am trying to graph this function of temperature to specific volume but the function is so skewed that the figure that I am not being able to make the figure I desire.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = [0.00100034, 0.00100184, 0.00100441, 0.00100789, 0.00101027, 14.67, 14.867, 15.335, 15.801]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 45.806, 45.806, 50, 60, 70]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

This gives the figure

This is not what i want as it looks like x is constant as y increases for small value of x but i want it to be slanted and show that y increases as x increases for small values of x.
I tried to use log by using the code as below:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = [0.00100034, 0.00100184, 0.00100441, 0.00100789, 0.00101027, 14.67, 14.867, 15.335, 15.801]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 45.806, 45.806, 50, 60, 70]
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()


but it causes the figure to be

which is even worse as not only the previous problem is still present but its also looks like x is constant as y increases for higher values of x.
Then i tried using breakpoints by using the code
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 45.806, 45.806, 50, 60, 70]
x = [0.00100034, 0.00100184, 0.00100441, 0.00100789, 0.00101027, 14.67, 14.867, 15.335, 15.801]


bax = brokenaxes(xlims=((.001, .002), (14, 16)))

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()

but this also dosent solve the problem as it causes the figure to be

I want the figure to look something like this

where it is clear that y increases as x increases for small values of x as well as for very large values of x and it needs to be slanted on both ends
I have seen many stackoverflow questions and have asked chatgpt multiple times but i couldn't get the answer

The first two points have a slope of 6666666.667, while the last two have a slope of 21.459. It is very difficult to show both scales at the same time.

It indeed looks like your data is so skewed that it is pretty much impossible without some very manual operations on the x axis

You could plot the data across two side-by-side axes, if you don't mind a gap:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import numpy as np

x = [0.00100034, 0.00100184, 0.00100441, 0.00100789, 0.00101027, 14.67, 14.867, 15.335, 15.801]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 45.806, 45.806, 50, 60, 70]

fig, (ax_low, ax_high) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, layout='constrained', width_ratios=[1, 2])

# Plot two parts of the data with the (x[4], y[4]) in both sets.
ax_low.plot(x[:5], y[:5])
ax_high.plot(x[4:], y[4:])

# Remove inside and top spines and ticks.
ax_low.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax_low.spines.top.set_visible(False)

ax_high.spines.left.set_visible(False)
ax_high.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax_high.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)

# Set the inside xlim to the common x data point.
ax_low.set_xlim(right=x[4])
ax_high.set_xlim(left=x[4])

# Add / to the ends of the x spines.
marker = MarkerStyle('|', transform=Affine2D().rotate_deg(135))
ax_low.plot(1, 0, "k", marker=marker, transform=ax_low.transAxes, clip_on=False, in_layout=False, markersize=18)
ax_high.plot(0, 0, "k", marker=marker, transform=ax_high.transAxes, clip_on=False, in_layout=False, markersize=18)

# Connect the ends of the data lines with a dotted line.
cp = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(x[4], y[4]), xyB=(x[4], y[4]), coordsA=ax_low.transData, coordsB=ax_high.transData)
cp.set_linestyle('dotted')
cp.set_color('C0')
fig.add_artist(cp)

# Rotate the long x-labels so we can distinguish them
ax_low.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=30)

plt.show()



Probably you could lose the gap if you turn off constrained layout and adjust the subplot positions yourself.

Get rid of layout="constrained" and replace it with gridspec_kw={"wspace":0}.

Though, ideally, something should show/say that the scale of the axes changes in the middle.

Thanks, this is exactly what i wanted. Although is there a way to use gridspec_kw={"wspace":0} as well as have a small a small symbol like ---//--- in the x axis to show where the scales are changing. As it is not clear what the value of y is when x goes from 0.001010 to 2 in the figure you made. I was thinking of something like https://ibb.co/yBJSXhh .
Or signifying in any way that the ending point of x axis of left graph is the same value as starting point of x axis of right graph.

OK I added some // on the ends of the spines by adapting this example and also added a ConnectionPatch to join up the two blue lines with a dotted one.
